# «The more that farther data are correlated, the higher L is» Is this correct?

Tags: grammar

I've wrote the following sentence:
«The more that farther data are correlated, the higher L is»

I mean to say that the farther data points are correlated, and the more correlated they are, the higher the value of L.

How would I write the above in a short sentence just like in the quote?

Edit: There are far and close points. L gives the intensity of correlation of points. As L increases, that intensity increases, but its change is more noticeable on the far points.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking. Are you saying there are "farther data," data that are farther away, either physically or in reference to the data elements referencing location, and the more those farther data are correlated, the higher the value of L?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Yes, I think so.

Comment: Well, since it's still unclear, I won't post an answer, but if you work out that that's what you mean, I will. Until then, if that is what you mean, what you've suggested is fine, except I would switch the last two words (i.e., "The more farther data are correlated, the higher L is."). You might also consider using the verb "becomes" instead of "is." Your other suggested phrase would work, too, if that's what you mean (i.e., "The more farther data are correlated, the higher the value of L.).

Comment: By the way, if that is what you mean, you maybe should consider editing your question and editing the sentence itself to add "that" between "more" and "farther" (i.e., "The more *that* farther data...") so that it's not misconstrued as you redundantly modifying the already comparative modifier "farther" with the comparative modifier "more," like when people say, "I'm more happier when it's sunny outside," or, "It's more farther than I thought."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman thanks for the suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 0):

"Farther" denotes something being away from something else. "Further" means additional, and so would be a bit better, but both are inferior to, and redundant with, "more". The only case I can think of where "The more farther data are correlated" would make sense is if there are close data point, and far data points, and L depends on the far data points being correlated. That is, if "farther" modifies "data points" rather than "correlated", then that would work. If that is what you mean, it would be clearer if you said "The more that farther data points".

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I follow you. I've edited my question, based on your answer/thoughts.